# Find the major product when Benzoquinone reacts with HBr

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

> What is the major product when Benzoquinone reacts with $\ce{HBr}$ ?

**My effort**: I thought it would be an $\text{SN}_{1}$ mechanism, but the carbocation at either double bond wouldn't be stable.

Comment: Please don't introduce Mathjax code to your question titles due to some [issues](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/149/ce-prepended-to-equations-in-url-slug/151?s=3|0.6803#151) $\ldots$ Unless, you're talking about cerium hydrogen bromide.

Comment: First, the acid will protonate the carbonyl to give a delocalized carbocation. Where will the nucleophile ($\ce{Br^{-}}$) attack; attack at which position can lead to a stable (aromatic) product by loss of $\ce{H^{+}}$?